# Error when using include inheritance dependencies

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I'm following [this tutorial](http://renaun.com/blog/2010/08/flex-hero-rsl-enhancements-and-monkey-patching/) to find out how to monkey patch the Flex SDK and I am coming across an error. It says to add the compiler argument, "-include-inheritance-dependencies-only". When I do I get the error,

```
When using -include-inheritance-dependencies-only classes must be specified using -include-classes.
```

However the article doesn't mention this case or maybe I missed a step? I have used -include-classes in an ANT script before but since I am using Flash Builder and this article is using Flash Builder I am thinking this is an error on my part.

**MORE INFO**
I have a Flex project, a library project and created a new library project that contains my Flex patched classes. In my new library project, "MyPatchedFlex" I have a class called FlexSprite. It is the class that has been patched. In my library and my Flex project class I've added a source path to the source directory in "MyPatchedFlex". I have the Flex project and library project set the Flex SDK to MergedIntoCode.

When running and debugging the project locally and remotely it loads fine and my patch is working. When I load the project on another computer that has the *Flash Player release player* then the Flex project never finishes loading. So that is why I'm trying to follow this example and go this route to get my project to load in the release player. If I don't have to patch the project this way and it has to do with a policy file or something else I would be happy to do that instead.

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 with Flex 4.6.

**UPDATE**
I might have solved it by going into Project Properties > Flex Library Build Path > Classes and choosing, "Select classes to include in the library" instead of choosing, "Include all classes from all source paths." At least for now the error has gone away.

Comment: This may be solved by choosing, "Select classes to include in the library" in project properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it could be a bug in Flash Builder or MXMLC. Choosing, "Select classes to include in the library" in project properties appears to have fixed the issue. Possibly selecting it, applying the changes and then deselecting it *may* also work.